# 1px wide line in outlook appears with bigger size

Tags: css, outlook, height, line

I'm making a inline mail for a client a the problem is I have a line that's supposed to be 1px wide and it becomes more wide in outlook, I know about how limited outlook and liberty is limited but I can't understand why this is not working in this case because similar mails made for other clients that look also the same are working perfectly.

Here is the fragment of the code that's giving me the problem.

```html
    <table width="" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
        <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
          <td height="8px" style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #424040 !important; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 8px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 8px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">&nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
          <td class="text-center" style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #424040 !important; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">
            <center style="min-width: 387px; width: 100%;">
              <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                    <td height="1" bgcolor="#c4c4c4" style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #424040 !important; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1px; font-weight: normal; height: 1px; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
          <td height="20px" style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #424040 !important; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">&nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
          <td style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #424040 !important; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">
            <font color="#424040">
              <p style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #424040 !important; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;">
                some text Here
              </p>
              <br>
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
          <td height="20px" style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #424040 !important; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">&nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the line width to be 1px, add the following to the line td style:

```
width: 1px;
display: inline-block;
```